# Solve $2 \cos x + 1 = \cos x$ for all values of $x$ on $ [0,2\pi]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm wondering how many values would come up in the solution. Would it only be two and if so what are the values?

Comment: What makes you think there are only two solutions?

Comment: Because it gives us [0,2pi] so I just assumed there would only be two solutions.

Comment: Have you tried to sketch a graph?

Comment: I'm doing that now.

Comment: As @SteveX says, for trigonometric equations it is ALWAYS useful to sketch the graph on the interval given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve as you would any other equation, but take into account the periodicity of the cosine function.

$2 \cos x + 1 = \cos x$ implies that $\cos x = -1$ and hence $x = \arccos(-1)$. In the range $[0, 2\pi]$, there is only the solution $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it reduces to $\cos x = -1$ and on your interval what value of $\cos x$ is equal to $-1$?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions $ x = \pm \pi $  are *two, coincident*, roots